# Adding an href link within a Bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

[image: popover]

I have used Bootstrap popovers and in this one, I'd like to add an href="somelink". But this seems impossible to do with the current code situation:

```
 <a 
          tabindex="0" 
          class="btn btn-link" 
          role="button" 
          data-toggle="popover" 
          data-trigger="focus" 
          title="Reaction Time (s)" 
          data-content="Enter the time it takes for a driver to react.
          Reaction times vary with age, distractions, alcohol or drug usage etc.
          The unit is seconds.">
              <i class="far fa-question-circle fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
```

What do I need to do to get an href into that popover text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `html:true` while initializing your popover.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(function () {
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({html:true})//add html as true to use html 
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-link" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Reaction Time (s)" data-content="Enter the time it takes for a driver to react.
          Reaction times vary with age, distractions, alcohol or drug usage etc.
          The unit is seconds <a href='yoururl'>something</a>.">
  <i class="far fa-question-circle fa-2x">Click</i>
</a>
```

Also check [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#options) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for this. This looks like it will work. I will give this a whirl.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting options `html` as `true` and `sanitize` as `false`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/javascript/#sanitizer

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
  sanitize: false
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-link" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-trigger="focus" title="Reaction Time (s)" data-content="Enter the time it takes for a driver to react.
          Reaction times vary with age, distractions, alcohol or drug usage etc.
          The unit is seconds. <a href='https://stackoverflow.com/'>Go</a>">
  <i class="far fa-question-circle fa-2x"></i>?
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this?

```js
$("#testpopover").popover({
 html: true,
 title:"React time(s)",
 content: "Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum."+
 "<a class='btn btn-default'>HTML in popover</a>"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div style="width:100%; height:500px; margin-top:15%">
<a type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="testpopover">popover</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll give this a try and see if it works. I had attempted to use the html: true, but I still couldn't get the anchor tag in because the whole thing is anchored to an icon for the popover. But I'll see if this works.